# How do I know if an optical drive is able to read CAV written DVD?

Tags: dvd, compatibility, optical-media

Some TV DVD recorder use CAV *(Constant angular velocity)* to record TV programs. The problem is that most optical drives from the PC world can't read such DVDs...

So, How I can detect if the drive installed my computer is able to read DVDs written at constant speed?
I don't care about the method, except the one which consist of buying a DVD of that kind and feeling having wasted money.

Comment: Sounds like something that would be listed in the specifications of the device itself

Comment: @user2284570 and the beauty of digital data is that, it doesn't matter *how* you write the 0's and 1's to the disc, or how *fast* you do it - it only matters that *those exact 0's and 1's* get written to the disc.  At that point, it is simply a DVD which can be decoded by any DVD reader - regardless of the speed regulation method that particular drive uses.

Comment: @Breakthrough : No, because the length of bit varies on the DVD with **CAV** so their is a little waste of storage. As all early drives support reading today's technology, CLV support isn't a consumer requirement. Modern drives use constant sized bit length. It must be something like this, or I would be able to read the DVD-R (which are not DVD-RAM) of my home recorder on any PC. Anyway, I finally got a CDR model IDE drive from HL storage.

Comment: @user2284570 In that case, can you share with us the particular model of TV DVD Recorder you used to originally make the discs?

Answer (score 2):

*It doesn't matter*.  Any DVD drive should be able to read any DVD it is compatible with (+/- R).  **For CDs and DVDs, CAV/CLV only affects the speed** data is read from / written to the disk, [**not the density of the data**](http://www.cdspeed2000.com/faq.html#4) (unlike the LaserDisc / hard drive counterparts).  While the time it takes to read/write the data *to* that DVD will differ depending on if you use constant angular or linear velocity, and this may affect how *much* data can be written to the disc, it has nothing to do when reading the data back.

The physical length of a bit in a given track (called [linear/recording density](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/op/media_Density.htm)) often differs even in adjacent tracks, and thus the physical size of a bit is always changing throughout the disk.  While there is a **maximum** linear density (corresponding to a *minimum* bit length, constrained by the medium itself, which for optical media is the [wavelength/size of the laser](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/159245-new-optical-laser-can-increase-dvd-storage-up-to-one-petabyte)), in general there is no minimum density (even when using zones).

[Nero Disc Speed](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Nero-CD-DVD-Speed) can tell you what modes your DVD drive supports for reading/writing (see [this thread for more details](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/214141-DVD-Writer-vs-Recorder-CAV-vs-CLV).  As mentioned before, it shouldn't matter what method a DVD was *written* with - your drive simply reads the binary data at the sectors on the disc (the *how* being CAV/CLV/etc...).  It will only affect the *data transfer rate* during reads/writes, depending on the drive's mode.

---

As an aside, most [modern DVD drives *use *both* methods*](http://static.highspeedbackbone.net/pdf/LG%2016X%20Blu-Ray%20Burner%20Data%20Sheet.pdf) - CAV for reading for the highest throughput, and CLV/(P)CAV for writing (depends on the write speed being used).  Likewise, such a disc could be read with a CLV-based drive **just fine**.  The only difference would be the drive would read the data back at a *constant* rate, instead of as in a CAV drive, where the read speed would slowly increase as the laser moves closer to the edge of the disc.

Comment: Yeah, I would've posted the same thing, except I'm confused why the OP is saying "it restricts the disc to be read in the same drive where it was recorded"... are you sure the OP is wrong here, or are we missing something?

Comment: Outside of Laserdiscs and hard drives (which are specific to a particular manufacturer/device anyways), yes you can read any CD in any CD drive and any DVD in any DVD drive.  One issue with older DVD hardware was compatibility between DVD-R and DVD+R media, which may be a related issue in this case.

Comment: @Breakthrough : No, using CAV is a well-known kind of method for preventing copyright infringement before DRMs. But let's take a [more well-known example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Nintendo_optical_discs#Raw_read_protection...).

Comment: @user2284570 not only can I can find several tutorials for backing up both Gamecube and Wii discs using a PC DVD drive, I have done it myself.  While you **do** require a drive that supports specific hardware commands (in particular, the [vendor-specific command to dump the read error buffer](http://www.gc-forever.com/wiki/index.php?title=RawDump)), not on the drive's capability to use CLV/CAV: "**The data comes through Raw from the drive (scrambled by the scrambling key) but RawDump determines the seeds on the fly to produce an unscrambled ISO.**"

Comment: Also, from [**the same Wikipedia page you linked**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Nintendo_optical_discs#CAV.3F), it is still apparent that CAV/CLV is irrelevant here.  GameCube discs are encrypted and obfuscated, but can still be read by most PC DVD drives.  See [this article](http://debugmo.de/2008/11/anatomy-of-an-optical-medium-authentication/) for details the encryption/obfuscation algorithm, which requires a DVD drive with the ability to dump the read-error buffer.  This particular method uses the error correcting data in the DVD itself as part of the encryption/obfuscation method.

Comment: @Breakthrough No, you need an early DVD drive. Anyway, encryption shouldn't make any raw read attempt at any disk blocks reported as bad. It should only make it impossible to acess the data meaning, not making eaven impossible to get the disk capacity. But in my case there is no encryption.

Comment: It doesn't make raw read attempts report as bad, it's to allow low-level access to the burst-cutting area.  And disk capacity can only be obtained in the case the DVD has a valid filesystem that can be read by the operating system you're using (which is irrelevant in the Nintento case).  And again, in the same article you linked to, it's further doubted that CLV/CAV has anything to do at all with copyright infringement, let alone your ability to read the data.  Again, a DVD drive does not care how physically long a 0 and a 1 are in a given track.

Comment: @user2284570 Can you provide the details on the particular model of TV DVD Recorder you were using?  At this point I'm willing to argue it's the way your particular discs were mastered, and there was a different copy protection mechanism in place.